# Django as a websocket client

Tags: python, django, docker, websocket

I know that [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can be used to make websocket server, not client. So I used [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to relay websocket incoming message to my Django like this:

```
async def relay():
    source_server = 'ws://source.example/ws/message'  # This is an external server
    target_server = 'ws://target.example/ws/message'  # This is my Django server
    async for target in websockets.connect(target_server):
        try: 
            async for source in websockets.connect(source_server):
                try:    
                    while True:
                        try:
                            message = await source.recv()
                            await target.send()
                            # log message
                        except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
                            # lost source server or target server or both
                            raise(e) 
                        except Exception as e:
                            # did not lose servers
                            continue
                except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
                    # lost source server or target server or both
                    if target.close_code is not None:
                        # lost target server and need to start from the outer for loop
                        # (to get a new target websocket connection)
                        source.disconnect()       
                        raise(e)
                    # lost source server and will continue the inner for loop 
                    # (to get a new source websocket connection)
                    continue
               except Exception as e:
                    # did not lose any server and will continue the inner for loop 
                    # (to get a new source websocket connection)
                    continue
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
            # lost target server and will continue the outer for loop
            # (to get a new target websocket connection)
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            # did not lose any server and will start the outer for loop   
            # (to get a new target websocket connection)
            continue 

asyncio.run(relay())
```

Understandably, this is not the most efficient code-up. But this is what I can think of.
I run this code as a Docker container (let's call it relay container) along side with my Django Docker containers (with the same Docker image as Django of course).

Here's my questions:

1. Is there a way to make Django a websocket client? (I want to save one container for the relay). For your information, I run Django container (using Daphne), two Celery (one for beat and one for worker) containers.
2. If I bring down the relay container, it takes long time (five to ten seconds) to be down. The exit code is Out Of Memory. What causes the problem? How can I shutdown the container gracefully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to run websocket-client in django.
First is using custom commands, you can refer the answer of @Scorpionk in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166142/contacting-another-websocket-server-from-inside-django-channels). But at this way, the websocketclient app will run separately with the main app which makes it hard to share values or variables between them.

Apart from that, the other way is using threading. So wrapping the scripts into threading will make it a non-blocking program. Let's say you create a django project "djwsclient", I will wrap your codes into djwsclient/djwsclient/asgi.py like below:

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djwsclient.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
async def relay():
    source_server = 'ws://source.example/ws/message'  # This is an external server
    target_server = 'ws://target.example/ws/message'  # This is my Django server
    async for target in websockets.connect(target_server):
        try: 
            async for source in websockets.connect(source_server):
                try:    
                    while True:
                        try:
                            message = await source.recv()
                            await target.send()
                            # log message
                        except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
                            # lost source server or target server or both
                            raise(e) 
                        except Exception as e:
                            # did not lose servers
                            continue
                except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
                    # lost source server or target server or both
                    if target.close_code is not None:
                        # lost target server and need to start from the outer for loop
                        # (to get a new target websocket connection)
                        source.disconnect()       
                        raise(e)
                    # lost source server and will continue the inner for loop 
                    # (to get a new source websocket connection)
                    continue
               except Exception as e:
                    # did not lose any server and will continue the inner for loop 
                    # (to get a new source websocket connection)
                    continue
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
            # lost target server and will continue the outer for loop
            # (to get a new target websocket connection)
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            # did not lose any server and will start the outer for loop   
            # (to get a new target websocket connection)
            continue 

def runWs():
    asyncio.run(relay())

import threading
threading.Thread(target=runWs).start()
```

Hope my answer helps you out.